# What is Win32/Kryptik.FM?

Tags: virus

ESET detected this trojan, but I cannot find any information on the Internet on *what it is*.  Google is only returning links on how to remove it, or what files have been detected to contain it.

Semantec's threat database [doesn't have it listed](http://searchg.symantec.com/search?q=Kryptik.FM&x=0&y=0&charset=utf-8&nh=10&hitsceil=100&st=1&proxystylesheet=symc_en_US&client=symc_en_US&site=symc_en_US_vir&output=xml_no_dtd&context=ent).  Same thing with [Mcafee's Threat Library](http://www.mcafee.com/apps/search/threat.aspx?q=Win32/Kryptik.FM%20trojan&v=malware).

What website can I go to that will tell me what this trojan does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload the infected file to [VirusTotal](http://www.virustotal.com) and get results from more AVs, maybe you'll get another names for the mallware. For example in [this report](http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=6f0f26d1d46fe841ecc8e04b83155fb56aee6c77c7c2268beeca6287d3125338-1321298896), the reporter states that is it [Trojan.GrayBird](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2003-040217-2506-99) - unfortunatelly he does not explain his statement. I you search VirusTotal for "kryptik" there are few comments that it is a fake AV.

> Backdoor.Graybird is a back door Trojan Horse that gives its creator unauthorized access to your computer. The existence of the file, Svch0st.exe, is an indication of a possible infection. Backdoor.Graybird is a Delphi application.

Comment: Thank you not only for answering the question, but helping me find future answers to similar questions on my own in the future.  "Give a man a fish, he'll be fed for a night.  Teach a man how to fish..."